# Configuration translation is not saved

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm working on a page where the backend needs to work in different languages.

That's why I started translating individual labels in the configuration translation (/admin/config/regional/config-translation). After I looked at the first changes, I realized that the terms were not translated.

I went back to the translation page and see that my changes have been overwritten with the original language again.
So I re-translated and saved the term, which showed a success message. Then I called the translation again and it was again the value of the original language there.

Is the translation generally broken or do I have to do a specific setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug created by a module. Which enterd the system a bit to early.